# Need to GET a REST API within async function in Slack App Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

I'm trying  to create an app for Slack that calls an external api when a command is called. I've done the following. But the problem is the Slack framework uses an `await`

```
app.command("/command", async({ ack, payload, context })=>{
  ack();
  var details;
  try{
    apiHandler(function(details) {
    const result = await app.client.chat.postMessage({  //<--- error here
      token: context.botToken,
      channel: payload.channel_id,
      blocks: [
        {
          type: "section",
          text: {
            type: "mrkdwn",
            text: details
          },
        }
      ],
      text: "Message from Test App"
    });
      console.log(details);
    });
  }catch(error)
  {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

//helper function:
function apiHandler(callback) {
  let XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
     xhr.open("GET","API-URL",true);
     xhr.onload = function()
     {
         if(this.status===200){
           callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText););
         }
       }
       xhr.send();
}
```

When I start the node, I get the following:

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

I'm very new to node.js and I'm completely blank on what to do

Comment: `apiHandler` is not an `async` function

Comment: @nopassport1 — Nor is the anonymous function passed to it.

Comment: @Quentin anonymous function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the async keyword on `apiHandler(async function(details) {`